# How to use subdomain with ActiveAdmin on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, subdomain

I'm trying to access the ActiveAdmin with subdomain "admin.localhost.local:3030" instead of namespace "localhost:3030/admin". I looked it up and I found that I should change the default namespace in "config/initializers/active_admin.rb" to false

```
config.default_namespace = false
```

and I surrounded the routes in "routes.rb" with subdomain constraints

```
constraints :subdomain => "admin" do
    ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
end
```

also, I changed "/etc/hosts" localhost line to be able to test on my machine

```
127.0.0.1    admin.localhost.local
```

but for some reason, it still doesn't work. I'm trying to access the subdomain by writing admin.localhost.local:3030 and this is what I get from the browser:
"The admin.localhost.local page isn’t working.
admin.localhost.local redirected you too many times."

Comment: the confusing thing is that "localhost:3030" is still working

Answer (score 0):

The infinite redirect could be because of the Devise configuration. Try the suggestion here:

```
constraints :host => 'admin.spikeatschool.local' do
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config.merge(:path => '')
end
```

https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/691#issuecomment-8583834